# Domain Driven Design: Domain Service, Application Service

Tags: architecture, domain-driven-design

Can someone explain the difference between domain and application services by providing some examples? And, if a service is a domain service, would I put the actual implementation of this service within the domain assembly and if so, would I also inject repositories into that domain service? Some info would be really helpful.

Comment: feel free to check this: youtu.be/MfEpw2WXXyk

Answer (score 523, accepted):

Services come in 3 flavours: **Domain Services**, **Application Services**, and **Infrastructure Services**.

- **Domain Services** : Encapsulates
  *business logic* that doesn't naturally
  fit within a domain object, and are **NOT** typical CRUD operations – those would belong to a *Repository*.
- **Application Services** : Used by
  external consumers to talk to your
  system (think *Web Services*).  If consumers need access to CRUD operations, they would be exposed here.
- **Infrastructure Services** : Used to
  abstract technical concerns (e.g.
  MSMQ, email provider, etc).

Keeping Domain Services along with your Domain Objects is sensible – they are all focused on domain logic.  And yes, you can inject Repositories into your Services.

Application Services will typically use both Domain Services *and* Repositories to deal with external requests.

Comment: Where would you put the commands and queries by CQRS? Which service generates them and which service handles them?

Comment: I think Application Services should be indepent of technical details like "web services", they are used by such services. See [Services in Domain-Driven Design](http://gorodinski.com/blog/2012/04/14/services-in-domain-driven-design-ddd/)

Comment: Think twice before using any kind of service classes. Chances are that you can go [without them](https://hackernoon.com/you-dont-need-a-domain-service-class-in-ddd-9ecd3140782) and your code can end up being way more clear and maintainable.

Comment: This is a great answer, but it needs references to books and authors (to make it even better).

Answer (score 143):

<sup>(If you don't feel like reading, there's a summary at the bottom :-)</sup>

I too have struggled with the precise definition of application services. Although Vijay's answer was very helpful to my thinking process a month ago, I have come to disagree with part of it.

### Other resources

There's very little information about application services. Subjects like aggregate roots, repositories and domain services are discussed extensively, but application services are only mentioned briefly or left out altogether.

The MSDN Magazine article [An Introduction To Domain-Driven Design](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419654.aspx) describes application services as a way to transform and/or expose your domain model to external clients, e.g. as a WCF service. This is how Vijay describes application services too. From this point of view, application services are an **interface to your domain**.

Jeffrey Palermo's articles on the Onion Architecture (part [one](http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/the-onion-architecture-part-1/), [two](http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/the-onion-architecture-part-2/) and [three](http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/the-onion-architecture-part-3/)) are a good read. He treats application services as **application-level concepts**, such as a user's session. Although this is closer to my understanding of application services, it's still not in line with my thoughts on the subject.

### My thoughts

I have come to think of application services as **dependencies provided by the application**. In this case the application could be a desktop application or a WCF service.

#### Domain

Time for an example. You start out with your domain. All entities and any domain services that don't depend on external resources are implemented here. Any domain concepts that depend on external resources are defined by an interface. Here is a possible solution layout (project name in bold):

```
My Solution
- My.Product.Core (My.Product.dll)
  - DomainServices
      IExchangeRateService
    Product
    ProductFactory
    IProductRepository
```

The `Product` and `ProductFactory` classes have been implemented in the core assembly. The `IProductRepository` is something that is probably backed by a database. The implementation of this is not the domain's concern and is therefore defined by an interface.

For now, we'll focus on the `IExchangeRateService`. The business logic for this service is implemented by an external web service. However, its concept is still part of the domain and is represented by this interface.

#### Infrastructure

The implementation of the external dependencies are part of the application's infrastructure:

```
My Solution
+ My.Product.Core (My.Product.dll)
- My.Product.Infrastructure (My.Product.Infrastructure.dll)
  - DomainServices
      XEExchangeRateService
    SqlServerProductRepository
```

`XEExchangeRateService` implements the `IExchangeRateService` domain service by communicating with [xe.com](http://www.xe.com/). This implementation can be used by your applications that utilize your domain model, by including the infrastructure assembly.

#### Application

Note that I haven't mentioned application services yet. We'll look at those now. Let's say we want to provide an `IExchangeRateService` implementation that uses a cache for speedy lookups. The outline of this decorator class could look like this.

```
public class CachingExchangeRateService : IExchangeRateService
{
    private IExchangeRateService service;
    private ICache cache;

    public CachingExchangeRateService(IExchangeRateService service, ICache cache)
    {
        this.service = service;
        this.cache = cache;
    }

    // Implementation that utilizes the provided service and cache.
}
```

Notice the `ICache` parameter? This concept is not part of our domain, so it's not a domain service. It's an **application service**. It's a dependency of our infrastructure that may be provided by the application. Let's introduce an application that demonstrates this:

```
My Solution
- My.Product.Core (My.Product.dll)
  - DomainServices
      IExchangeRateService
    Product
    ProductFactory
    IProductRepository
- My.Product.Infrastructure (My.Product.Infrastructure.dll)
  - ApplicationServices
      ICache
  - DomainServices
      CachingExchangeRateService
      XEExchangeRateService
    SqlServerProductRepository
- My.Product.WcfService (My.Product.WcfService.dll)
  - ApplicationServices
      MemcachedCache
    IMyWcfService.cs
  + MyWcfService.svc
  + Web.config
```

This all comes together in the application like this:

```
// Set up all the dependencies and register them in the IoC container.
var service = new XEExchangeRateService();
var cache = new MemcachedCache();
var cachingService = new CachingExchangeRateService(service, cache);

ServiceLocator.For<IExchangeRateService>().Use(cachingService);
```

### Summary

A complete application consists of three major layers:

- domain
- infrastructure
- application

The domain layer contains the domain entities and stand-alone domain services. Any domain *concepts* (this includes domain services, but also repositories) that depend on external resources, are defined by interfaces.

The infrastructure layer contains the implementation of the interfaces from the domain layer. These implementations may introduce new *non-domain* dependencies that have to be provided the application. These are the application services and are represented by interfaces.

The application layer contains the implementation of the application services. The application layer may also contain additional implementations of domain interfaces, if the implementations provided by the infrastructure layer are not sufficient.

Although this perspective may not match with the general DDD definition of services, it does separate the domain from the application and allows you to share the domain (and infrastructure) assembly between several applications.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your thoughts but I have one question. How to create some IDomainService where some method takes data from Controller (MVC)? Suppose we have Controller method Save(RequestModel model). RequestModel belongs to UI rather than Domain Layer. How should I pass data to our service? I can't do IDomainService.Save(model).

Comment: @dario-g: You'd have to reconstruct/repopulate your domain model from the request model and pass the domain model to the domain service. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2206005/332100) may provide you with some ideas. If not, let me know and I'll see if I have some time to add an answer to the other question.

Comment: Proposed question is not quite good. Very often You need to do some action on domain object. It is not simply copy values from object to object. Worse when you must do it on certain different domain objects not one. So, I'm looking forward... Take a look on this: http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/jimmy_bogard/archive/2009/09/17/the-case-for-two-way-mapping-in-automapper.aspx

Comment: @dario-g: Sorry, but I must be overlooking your problem. Could you create a new question which clearly demonstrates your problem with an example?

Comment: @Niels: ok, I read this once again and understand. I need to call from Controller an ApplicationService, pass there my ViewModel. Then create DomainObject (assign properties from ViewModel/execute proper method on it) and pass it to DomainService. :)

Comment: Why do you put interface of infrastructure layer's service in domain layer instead of infrastructure layer itself?

Comment: @Tiendq: Do you mean the `IExchangeRateService` interface? This is a domain concept, i.e. something that is included in your customer's ubiquitous language. Other parts of your domain may depend on this service, which is why its interface in defined in the domain layer. But because its implementation involves an external web service, the implementing class resides in the infrastructure layer. This way the domain layer is only concerned with business logic.

Comment: Yes, I meant IExchangeRateService. So it means that the infrastructure layer depends on the domain layer, doesn't it? I have thought that the infrastructure layer that contains infrastructure services which are commodities and independent of any domain business.

Comment: @Tiendq: In a traditional layered architecture, the infrastructure is usually domain-agnostic. But in the Onion Architecture (see links in my answer) the infrastructure implements the domain's external dependencies. But I wouldn't say the infrastructure *depends* on the domain, it just *references* it. I have taken the term 'infrastructure' from the Onion Architecture, but 'externals' may be a better name.

Comment: I disagree with the part where you disagree with Vijay and here's why.  CachingExchangeRateService is an infrastructure concern.  Even though you're generically accepting an ICache, the implementation for that ICache depends on the technology involved (ie. Web, Windows). Just because it's generic does not make it an application service. An application service is your domain's API.  What if you wanted to reveal your domain to someone else writing an app, what will they use?  Application Services, and they may not need caching so your caching impl is useless to them (ie.why it's infrastructure)

Answer (score 70):

The best resource that helped me understand the difference between an Application Service and a Domain Service was the java implementation of Eric Evans' cargo example, found [here](http://dddsample.sourceforge.net/characterization.html). If you download it, you can check out the internals of RoutingService (a Domain Service) and the BookingService, CargoInspectionService (which are Application Services).

My 'aha' moment was triggered by two things:

- Reading the description of the Services in the link above, more precisely this sentence:

> Domain services are expressed in terms of the ubiquitous language and
> the domain types, i.e. the method arguments and the return values are
> proper domain classes.

- Reading this [blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/pgielens/archive/2006/05/31/Applying-the-Application-Layer-in-Domain-Driven-Design.aspx), especially this part:

> What I find a big help in separating the apples from the oranges is
> thinking in terms of application workflow. All logic concerning the
> application workflow typically end up being Application Services
> factored into the Application Layer, whereas concepts from the domain
> that don’t seem to fit as model objects end up forming one or more
> Domain Services.

Comment: I agree, this is exactly how I define Application Services, and it fit all the situations I have met so far. Domain Services deal with everything related to domain objects, but that go beyond the scope of a single entity. Ex: BookReferencesService.GetNextAvailableUniqueTrackingNumber(), the focus is clearly business rules*. Regarding Application Service, it's exactly what you describe, most of the time I begin by putting this business workflow into my controller actions, and when I notice it I refactor this logic in the application service layer. We might say that this layer is for use cases

Comment: *And such domain service interfaces are consumed by the domain entities.

Comment: The blog post link is broken. Anyone able to find a working one?

Comment: How can we force to use domain service instead of domain entity? That knowledge need to be aware for all developers?

Answer (score 66):

From the Red Book (Implementing Domain Driven Design, by Vaughn Vernon), this is how I understand the concepts:

**Domain objects** (**entities** and **value objects**) encapsulate behavior required by the (sub)domain, making it natural, expressive, and understandable.

**Domain services** encapsulate such behaviors that do not fit in a *single* domain object. For example, a book library lending a `Book` to a `Client` (with corresponding `Inventory` changes) might do so from a domain service.

**Application services** handle the flow of use cases, including any additional concerns needed *on top of* the domain's. It often exposes such methods through its API, for consumption by external clients. To build on our previous example, our application service might expose a method `LendBookToClient(Guid bookGuid, Guid clientGuid)` that:

- Retrieves the `Client`.
- Confirms its permissions. (*Note how we have kept our domain model free of security / user management concerns. Such pollution could lead to many problems. Instead, we fulfill this technical requirement here, in our application service.*)
- Retrieves the `Book`.
- Calls the domain service (passing the `Client` and `Book`) to handle the *actual domain logic* of lending the book to the client. For instance, I imagine that confirming the book's availability is definitely part of the domain logic.

An application service should generally have a very simple flow. Complex application service flows often indicate that domain logic has leaked out of the domain.

As you can hopefully see, the **domain model** stays very *clean* this way, and is easy to understand and discuss with the domain experts, because it only contains its own, actual business concerns. The **application flow**, on the other hand, is *also* much easier to manage, since it is relieved of domain concerns, and becomes concise, and straightforward.

Comment: I would say that the **application service** is also the point where dependencies are resolved. Its method is a use case, a single flow, so it can make informed decisions on concrete implementations to use. Database transactions fit here as well.

Comment: Personally, I find that "permissions" is often more of a domain concern than people tend to think. For example, "only lend books to clients in good standing" sounds like a business rule to me. Although, of course, you may need some application-level logic to translate things like raw permissions into the domain-level "standing" status of a `Client` entity.

Comment: @Timo How to make sure/force so that we use domain service for a particular use-case?

Comment: @Timo "Calls the domain service (passing the Client and Book) to handle the actual domain logic of lending the book to the client" to which domain this action belongs? I mean "lending a book" is a part of "Book" domain model or "Client" domain model ?

Comment: @Ali.Rashidi `Book` and `Client` would be domain _objects_. The domain _model_ is the _entire_ model used to implement functionality in the business domain. Since lending a book to a client is presumably complex, a domain service may be involved, because the responsibilities of the process concern multiple entities: Is the book available? Does the client have space to lend more books? Is the client permitted to lend books in the first place (active subscription, no debts, etc.)? These are domain rules that need to be enforced somewhere in the model.

Comment: @timo then what will application services do ? we do all the business logic inside  the domain service.

Comment: @Ali.Rashidi An application service implementing `LendBook` might: Perform authentication and authorization. Interpret and validate the input contract model (e.g. `LendBookRequest`). Load `Client` and `Book`. Confirm that they exist or invalidate the request. Invoke the domain service to perform the domain logic. Adapt the result to an output contract model (e.g. `LendBookResponse`).
_(Remember, whereas the domain model is free to change, the contract model is hard to change. It needs to be stable, being part of your API, used by external contexts.)_

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 50):

**Domain service** is the extension of the domain. It should be seen only in the context of the domain. This is not some user action like for instance *close account* or something. The domain service fits where there is no state. Otherwise it would be a domain object. Domain service does something which makes sense only when being done with other collaborators (domain objects or other services). And that *making sense* is the responsibility of another layer.

**Application service** is that layer which initializes and oversees interaction between the domain objects and services. The flow is generally like this: get domain object (or objects) from repository, execute an action and put it (them) back there (or not). It can do more - for instance it can check whether a domain object exists or not and throw exceptions accordingly. So it lets the user interact with the application (and this is probably where its name originates from) - by manipulating domain objects and services. Application services should generally represent all possible *use cases*. Probably the best thing you can do before thinking about the domain is to create application service interfaces what will give you a much better insight in what you're really trying to do. Having such knowledge enables you to focus on the domain.

Repositories can generally speaking be injected into domain services but this is rather rare scenario. It is the application layer who does it most of the time though.

Comment: "The domain service fits where there is no state. Otherwise it would be a domain object." made it click for me. Thank you.

Comment: @Nick can you explain it ?

Comment: One of the best things I read about this diffícult distinction. Thx.

Answer (score 18):

Think a **Domain Service** as an object that implements business logic or business rules related logic on domain objects and this logic is difficult to fit into the same domain objects and also doesn't cause state change of the domain service *(domain service is an object without a "state" or better without a state that has a business meaning)* but eventually change the state only of the domain objects on which operates.

While an **Application Service** implements applicative level logic as user interaction, input validation, logic not related to business but to other concerns: authentication, security, emailing, and so on.., limiting itself to simply use services exposed by domain objects.

An example of this could be the following scenario thinked only for explaining purpose: *we have to implement a very little domotic utility app that executes a simple operation, that is "turn on the lights, when someone opens the door of an house's room to enter in and turn off the light when closes the door exiting from the room".*

Simplifying a lot we consider only 2 domain entities, which are not part of the same aggregate: **`Door`** and **`Lamp`**, each of them has 2 states, respectevely `open/closed` and `on/off`, and specific methods to operate state changes on them. The entities need to be part of different aggregates so that the following logic can't be implemented in the aggregate root.

In this case we need a domain service that executes the specific operation of turn on the light when someone opens the door from the outer to enter into a room, **because the door and the lamp objects cannot implement this logic in a way that we consider suited to their business nature**. This new domain service needs to encapsulate some business process that should always happen, triggered by some domain event/method.

We can call our domain service as **`DomoticDomainService`** and implement 2 methods: **`OpenTheDoorAndTurnOnTheLight`** and **`CloseTheDoorAndTurnOffTheLight`**, these 2 methods respectevely change the state of both objects `Door` and `Lamp` to **`open/on`** and **`closed/off`**.

The state of enter or exit from a room it isn't present in the domain service object and either in the domain objects, but will be implemented as simple user interaction by an **application service**, that we may call **`HouseService`**, that implements some event handlers as **`onOpenRoom1DoorToEnter`** and **`onCloseRoom1DoorToExit`**, and so on for each room *(this is only an example for explaining purpose..)*, that will respectively concern about call domain service methods to execute the attended behaviour *(we haven't considered the entity `Room` because it is only an example)*.

This example, far to be a well designed real world application, has the only purpose (as more times said) to explain what a Domain Service is and its difference from an Application Service, hope it is clear and useful.

Also, the example domain service above could easily be replaced by domain events which are used to explicitly implement side effects across one or multiple aggregates, but since these are not the subject of this question, I only mention them here so the reader can be aware of their existence and later decide which approach is better for them.

Comment: Hi Morteza, could you be more specific? Yours risks to be only a "judgement" without any real argument. Thank you

Answer (score 15):

> **Domain Services :** Methods that don’t really fit on a single entity or require access to the repository are contained within domain
>   services. The domain service layer can also contain domain logic of
>   its own and is as much part of the domain model as entities and value
>   objects.
>
> **Application Services :** The Application service is a thin layer that sits above the domain model and coordinates the application
>   activity. It does not contain business logic and does not hold the
>   state of any entities; however, it can store the state of a business
>   workflow transaction. You use an Application service to provide an API
>   into the domain model using the Request-Reply messaging pattern.

Millett,C (2010). Professional ASP.NET Design Patterns. Wiley Publishing. 92.

Answer (score 10):

**Domain Services**: A service that expresses a *business logic* that is not part of any Aggregate Root.

- You have 2 Aggregate:

  - `Product` which contains name and price.
  - `Purchase` which contains purchase date, list of products ordered with quantity and product price at that time, and payment method.
- `Checkout` is not part of either of these two models and is concept in your business.
- `Checkout` can be created as a Domain Service which fetches all product and compute the total price, pay the total by calling another Domain Service `PaymentService` with an implementation part of Infrastructure, and convert it into `Purchase`.

**Application Services**: A service that *"orchestrates"* or exercises Domain methods. This can be as simple as just your Controller.

This is the place where you usually do:

```
public String createProduct(...some attributes) {
  if (productRepo.getByName(name) != null) {
    throw new Exception();
  }

  productId = productRepository.nextIdentity();

  product = new Product(productId, ...some attributes);

  productRepository.save(product);

  return productId.value();
  // or Product itself
  // or just void if you dont care about result
}

public void renameProduct(productId, newName) {
  product = productRepo.getById(productId);

  product.rename(newName);

  productRepo.save(product);
}
```

You can do validations here like checking if a `Product` is unique. Unless a `Product` being unique is an invariant then that should be part of Domain Service that might be called `UniqueProductChecker` because it can't be part of `Product` class and it interacts with multiple Aggregates.

Here is full-blown example of DDD project: https://github.com/VaughnVernon/IDDD_Samples

You can find lots of examples of Application Service and a couple of Domain Service

Comment: Is it mandatory to validate and save entities only in Application Services? If I have entities A, B and C and all of them related to each other (A -> B -> C) and operation on A should cause changes to B and C by calling one Domain Service from another, how to do it?

Comment: > Is it mandatory to validate and save entities only in Application Services?
If you have to, then yes. Most of the times you have to check if an ID exists because otherwise you'll work on a null variable.

Comment: > If I have entities A, B and C and all of them related to each other (A -> B -> C) and operation on A should cause changes to B and C by calling one Domain Service from another, how to do it?

I'm not sure what you mean by "calling one Domain Service from another", but for reactions to changes of an Entity, you can use Events or just orchestrate it with Application service like: aggregateA.doOperation(), aggregateB.doAnother(). Search for: Orchestration vs Choreography

Comment: Thank you fo reply! "calling one Domain Service from another" - I mean, if I have a complex operation on entity A, then I have to use ADomainService. But this operation, in addition to entity A, affects entity B. The operation that must be performed on entity B in the ADomainService is also complex. So I have to use BDomainService from ADomainService. Now I doubt this approach :) But if I put this logic in the ApplicationService, wouldn't it break the encapsulation of business processes that should only be in the domain layer, not in application layer?

Comment: You can just emit event from your Domain Service if you think it should be in a Domain Service instead of Application Service.