# Domain Driven Design question about Services

Tags: oop, domain-driven-design

I'm reading Domain Driven Design Quickly and I'm having trouble understanding something.

When the author speaks of `Entities`, `Value Objects` and `Services`, is he speaking of the `Domain Model` (I mean, the concepts), or already about the implementation?

What is a `Service`? A `Controller`? A static class?

On p38 one can read:

> When a significant process or
>   transformation in the domain is not a
>   natural responsability of an Entity or
>   Value Object, add an operation to the
>   model as a standalone interface
>   declared as a Service. Define the
>   interface in terms of the language of
>   the model and make sure the operation
>   name is part of the Ubiquitous
>   Language. Make the Service stateless.

From this text, I can conclude:

a) If the `Service` is stateless, it can't be a `Controller`. Is it a static class / `Singleton`?

b) What does he mean with an `Interface`? I know what an interface is when coding, but if he is talking about interfaces he must be talking already about class diagrams and such and not so much about the `Domain Model`?

I'm getting confused, could anyone clear this out?

Thanks

Comment: Here is a glossary of terms http://domaindrivendesign.org/resources/ddd_terms

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DDD's core focus is around *understanding and clarity* - implementation details come afterwards.

A **Domain Service** is basically a class that contains business logic.. It doesn't have to be a static or a Singleton (here's a chance to read up on *Dependency Injection* and *Service Locators*).  The term *stateless* is also overloaded: in this context, it means that the Service shouldn't act like an *Entity.*

The **Interface** describes the methods of the Domain Service. Specifically, 'give the methods meaningful names - names that make sense to a business person'.

Unfortunately, the term **Service** is also overloaded.  See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268699/domain-driven-design-domain-service-application-service/2279729#2279729) for a description.