# How to avoid N+1 problem with DDD aggregate relations?

Tags: aggregate, domain-driven-design, ddd-repositories

I’ve read an article from Vaughn Vernon where he states that aggregates should only reference each other by identity.

Lets say i have aggregate A which has a reference to the identity of aggregate B. I’d like to display a list containing aggregate A with some columns from aggregate B in my UI.

That would mean i have to query aggregate A first, then i’d have to query aggregate B with the reference from aggregate A.

This seems to be a N+1 problem, how could i solve this while respecting the “reference by identity” rule?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not query your domain objects since they typically don't lend themselves to querying.  The domain is more concerned with the *command* / *transactional* side of things where you create and write away data.

On the other hand *querying* / *reporting* is more concerned with reading data.  To this end you can develop a light-weight query mechanism that is as close as is feasible to the data layer you are using.  As such you return rather raw data or *read models* (DTOs) along with whatever joining and data aggregation you need.

Comment: People mentioning that DTOs should be placed in Application Layer (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31438286/ddd-which-layer-dto-should-be-implemented). So **how** do we return DTOs if we are querying from Repository?

Comment: The short answer @YamiOdymel is that you don't return DTOs from a repository since it should be concerned with domain objects (entity / aggregate root).  I usually have a *data access* layer of sorts that would be used by the application layer to return the DTOs.  I tend to namespace the read model in a `Query` namespace, so I could have `Project.Person` entity and a `Project.Query.Person` read model.