# Do I need to define a DTO if it is exactly the same as the Domain Entity?

Tags: asp.net, domain-driven-design

We are using DDD and in a few cases, small Domain Entity objects are *exactly* the same as the data which needs to be exposed by the application layer to the caller.

I was reading: [DDD - which layer DTO should be implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31438286/ddd-which-layer-dto-should-be-implemented)

It makes sense DTO objects should not be declared in the Domain layer, but does that mean we should create an identical DTO... or is it acceptable the Application simply returns the Domain object *as* a DTO, since we may always refactor later to have a dedicated DTO if required?

Answer (score 2):

> is it acceptable the Application simply returns the Domain object as a DTO, since we may always refactor later to have a dedicated DTO if required?

There is, as far as I can tell, no authoritative definition of "acceptable"; if you and your team decide that the trade-offs are acceptable, who are we to argue?

---

A risk to keep in mind: refactoring later will often be more expensive than refactoring sooner (coupling tends to accrue over time).  The responsible calculation is something like opportunity cost of refactoring now vs a weighted average of the opportunity costs of refactoring later.

(There are, of course, compensating advantages for postponing the refactoring until the last responsible moment; among other things, future you is going to have a lot more information than present you does -- assuming you are disciplined about preserving information.)

Comment: Thanks. I suppose it doesn't break any DDD rules because the application is 'allowed' to access the domain (but not the opposite).