# ddd - is my Service a Domain one or an Application one?

Tags: domain-driven-design

I have trouble identifying if a Service I am creating is a Domain one or an Application one. From the book I read "Domain Driven Design in PHP", it is said that an Application service would be like a "User SignUp Request", accessing a Repository and verifying if a user exists or not. However they take the same example to implement it as a Domain Service, so I cannot differentiate both.

My situation is the following: I am creating a dynamic page builder. A Page as many Blocks, that are all a subclass of a Base Block. Each subclass of Base Block has its own business rules to allow the user to customize its design (basically it should return a form, different for each Block).

I am starting with the use case "A user wants to add a [Specific Block] to a Page".

I wonder if this is a Domain Service, or an Application Service. Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: What do you mean exactly by *"take the same example to implement it as a Domain Service"* ? I'm not sure how a self-respecting DDD book could fail to explain such a fundamental difference. Are you sure you read correctly ? A good article about services in DDD : http://gorodinski.com/blog/2012/04/14/services-in-domain-driven-design-ddd/

Comment: The book takes the exact same example: "A user wants to sign up" and implements it first as an Application Service, then as a Domain Service. However it seems like I was misunderstanding it. Your article was a great help, thanks !

Comment: Maybe the application service was calling the domain service in the book ?

Comment: Actually no, it was doing the exact same thing, but in a different manner. The Application one was using a DTO, while the Domain one was using the raw data, and checking some other things aswell (password validity)

Answer (score 3):

Your application services would typically be responsible for orchestrating a use case, and do something like loading / saving an aggregate from persistence.

i.e. something like:

```
public void SomeUseCase()
{
     var aggregate = _repository.Load(someId);
     aggregate.ApplySomeBehaviour(someDomainService);
     _repository.Save(aggregate);
}
```

whereas a Domain Service would be more domain behaviour specific, for example a RateCalculator - some object that doesn't fit into the Aggregate concept but contains behaviour you need to capture in your domain.

Possible duplicate of **[Domain Driven Design: Domain Service, Application Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268699/domain-driven-design-domain-service-application-service)**

Comment: That makes it even clearer, thank you !