# Spring MVC Controller implementation advice

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

Currently I have a domainObjectPersistenceService which calls DAO functions on the Domain Object, and I have a separate domainObjectDomainService which processes Business Logic.  For example, userPersistenceService and userDomainService.

I am unsure whether to handle the initial call to the domainObjectPersistenceService from the Controller directly, or call it from inside the domainObjectDomainService.

What is the preferred way?

```
@Controller
public class Controller {
   public controllerMethod(int fileId) {
      domainObject = domainObjectPersistenceService.getFile(fileId);

      data = domainObjectDomainService.processFile(domainObject);

      // convert data into DTO

      return dataDTO;
   }  
}
```

or

```
    @Controller
    public class Controller {
       public controllerMethod(int fileId) {
          // domainObjectDomainService handles persistence layer calls.
          data = domainObjectDomainService.processFile(fileId);

          // convert data into DTO

          return dataDTO;
       }  
    }
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Where are the transaction boundaries?

Comment: At the moment they are in the Persistence Service, but I have yet to introduce any advanced functionality that may require them in the "Domain" Service Layer.

Comment: So for the first of the  alternatives you create the object in kne transaction, then pass it into another transaction?

Comment: tbh, I am still learning about Transactions really.  I have merely annotated some retrieval methods with @transactional.  But your responses have given me some insight into considerations I must make.

Do you think splitting the persistence service and the domain service in this way is a bad idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Domain Driven Design: Domain Service, Application Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268699/domain-driven-design-domain-service-application-service)

In your case Controller is Application Service. It is an orchestrator, that retrieves objects from the repository and pass to the Domain Service.

 First way is correct.