# DDD, should I create a domain service just to save data?

Tags: java, design-patterns, architecture, domain-driven-design

I'm trying to folllow this guide https://www.baeldung.com/hexagonal-architecture-ddd-spring . After reading along I found this interesting approach

> Lastly, we should make sure that the Order will be always saved after
> each action. To do that, we'll define a **Domain Service**, which usually
> contains logic that can't be a part of our root:

So from what I understand **a domain service is what we use when  we can't fit business logic in a single domain object**. But what the guide did was just saving a single domain object to the database because we can't have the repository within our domain object right??. If that's the case why don't we just **let the controller have access to the repository** (some say it's bad practice some say "no" I don't even understand??) since we already put business logic in the domain object. so we would have something like this.

```
@PostMapping
public Mono<Order> addProduct(Request request) {
    return orderRepository.findById(request.orderId())
                          .map(order -> {
                              order.addProduct(reqeust.getProduct());
                              return order;
                          })
                          .flatMap(order-> orderRepository.save(order));
}.
```

Should we create an additional layer and call it **Domain Service** for saving data ? please help me understand best practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You definitely do not want any database code in your entities or domain services.

[Application Service is a place for operations](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2008/08/21/services-in-domain-driven-design/):

> In many cases, Application Services are the interface used by the
> outside world, where the outside world can’t communicate via our
> Entity objects, but may have other representations of them.
> Application Services could map outside messages to internal operations
> and processes, communicating with services in the Domain and
> Infrastructure layers to provide cohesive operations for outside
> clients.

Application services orchestrate calls to repositories and domain objects.

Comment: So in my case application service is the controller right or should I create another layer for application service?

Comment: @Patrick yeah, read more here [Domain Driven Design: Domain Service, Application Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268699/domain-driven-design-domain-service-application-service)